# For loop with np.arctan2

Tags: python, for-loop, numpy, trigonometry

i would like to use *np.arctan2* in a loop because i have a great number of slices to consider (so i have 3D array), but i have an error : "invalid number of arguments" but i work on 2D array as i use loop...

```
import numpy as np

Lx=500.
Ly=400.

x0 = Lx/2. 
y0 = Ly/2.

#stockage des valeurs de x0 servant au calcul de x0 optimal
stockx0 = []
for i in range(0,300,1):
    stock = Lx/2. + i
    stockx0.append(stock)

stockx0 = np.array(stockx0)
stockx0 = stockx0[np.newaxis,:]

YA, XA = np.mgrid[0:Ly, 0:Lx]

XA = XA[:, :, np.newaxis]*np.ones((XA.shape[0],XA.shape[1],stockx0.shape[1]))

YA = YA[:, :, np.newaxis]*np.ones((XA.shape[0],XA.shape[1],stockx0.shape[1]))

XA2 = []

for i in range(XA.shape[2]):
    stock = XA[:,:,i] - stockx0[0,i]
    XA2.append(stock)

XA2 = np.array(XA2)

YA = YA - y0

theta_list = []

for i in range(XA2.shape[0]):
      theta = -np.arctan2((YA[:,:,i],XA2[i,:,:]))
      theta_list.append(theta)

theta = np.asarray(theta_list)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`numpy.arctan2()`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.arctan2.html) expect two arguments, and you're supplying just one (a tuple). You need to remove one pair of parentheses:

```
theta = -np.arctan2((YA[:,:,i],XA2[i,:,:]))
                    ^--------------------^ THESE
```